# how to set default laravel migration from other tables dynamicly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, migration

i have table with two column amount_1 and amount_2 and i have column name real_price and i want to set default value for real_price in database to divide amount_1 to amount_2 and save
i try this in migration like below but it fails

```
            $table->double('real_price')->default('abs(`amount_1`) / greatest(abs(`amount_2`),1)');
```

error i get after run migrations

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'real_price'
```

is there any way to this in migration file ?

Answer (score 1):

Mysql and Postgresql do not allow to set calculated values by default

You can do the following:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('my_table', static function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->double('real_price');
    });

    DB::table('my_table')->update([
        'real_price' => DB::raw('abs(`amount_1`) / greatest(abs(`amount_2`),1)'),
    ]);
}
```

And to further set the value of real_price, you can use [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers)

Comment: this is what i found in my schema sql file   `real_price` double NOT NULL DEFAULT (abs(`amount_1`) / greatest(abs(`amount_1`),1)),